# Jenkins - How to get the return type of a method using Groovy

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to get the return type of a method in Jenkins using groovy script. Below is the code.

```
import jenkins.model.Jenkins
import hudson.model.Hudson

name = "demo_snippet"
intfs = hudson.model.FreeStyleProject.getInterfaces();
println 'Interfaces which FreestyleProject implements is : ' + intfs

def job = Hudson.instance.getJob(name)
println 'job name is ' + job

getJob_returntype = Hudson.instance.getJob(name).getReturnType()
println 'return type of  getJob is TopLevelItem : ' + getJob_returntype
```

This is the output

```
Interfaces which FreestyleProject implements is : [interface hudson.model.TopLevelItem]
job name is hudson.model.FreeStyleProject@9c9eb34[demo_snippet]
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: hudson.model.FreeStyleProject.getReturnType() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
```

***The getJob method returns TopLevelItem Interface name , how can I get that using getReturnType() or is there something equivalent to it to get the getJob_returntype value as TopLevelItem***